# How do I delay a function from executing after an event has been called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spinner, jquery-events

I have a spinner for a game I am building. I would like a question form to appear once the spinner has stopped spinning. Is there a way to delay the launch of the form after clicking spin?

```
/*WHEEL SPIN FUNCTION*/

$('#spin').click(function() {

    //add 1 every click
    clicks++;

    /*multiply the degree by number of clicks
    generate random number between 1 - 360,
    then add to the new degree*/

    var newDegree = degree * clicks;
    var extraDegree = Math.floor(Math.random() * (360 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    totalDegree = newDegree + extraDegree;

    /*let's make the spin btn to tilt every
    time the edge of the section hits
    the indicator*/

    $('#wheel .sec').each(function() {
        var t = $(this);
        var noY = 0;

        var c = 0;
        var n = 700;
        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            c++;
            if (c === n) {
                clearInterval(interval);
            }

            var aoY = t.offset().top;
            $("#txt").html(aoY);
            console.log(aoY);

            /*23.7 is the minimum offset number that
            each section can get, in a 30 angle degree.
            So, if the offset reaches 23.7, then we know
            that it has a 30 degree angle and therefore,
            exactly aligned with the spin btn*/

            if (aoY < 23.89) {
                console.log('<<<<<<<<');
                $('#spin').addClass('spin');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#spin').removeClass('spin');
                }, 100);
            }
        }, 10);

        $('#inner-wheel').css({
            'transform': 'rotate(' + totalDegree + 'deg)'
        });

        noY = t.offset().top;

    });
    //have form appear once the spinner stops

    showForm();

});

function showForm() {
    if (aoY > 0) {
        $("#formWrapper").show();
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure in this code what is stopping the spin, but I see a removeClass("spin") in a setTimeout function. Why not just trigger the form inside this function?

```
$('#spin').click(function() {

    //add 1 every click
    clicks++;

    /*multiply the degree by number of clicks
    generate random number between 1 - 360,
    then add to the new degree*/

    var newDegree = degree * clicks;
    var extraDegree = Math.floor(Math.random() * (360 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    totalDegree = newDegree + extraDegree;

    /*let's make the spin btn to tilt every
    time the edge of the section hits
    the indicator*/

    $('#wheel .sec').each(function() {
        var t = $(this);
        var noY = 0;

        var c = 0;
        var n = 700;
        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            c++;
            if (c === n) {
                clearInterval(interval);
            }

            var aoY = t.offset().top;
            $("#txt").html(aoY);
            console.log(aoY);

            /*23.7 is the minimum offset number that
            each section can get, in a 30 angle degree.
            So, if the offset reaches 23.7, then we know
            that it has a 30 degree angle and therefore,
            exactly aligned with the spin btn*/

            if (aoY < 23.89) {
                console.log('<<<<<<<<');
                $('#spin').addClass('spin');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#spin').removeClass('spin');
                    showForm();
                }, 100);
            }
        }, 10);

        $('#inner-wheel').css({
            'transform': 'rotate(' + totalDegree + 'deg)'
        });

        noY = t.offset().top;

    });
    //have form appear once the spinner stops



});

function showForm() {
    if (aoY > 0) {
        $("#formWrapper").show();
    };
}
```

---

**New Suggestion**

It looks like you're using css transforms/animations to animate the spinning of the wheel. Why not utilitze jQuery animate to do the animation? You could then tap into the complete method of jQuery animate to do something after the wheel stops spinning.

```
$('#inner-wheel').animate({ textIndent: 0 }, { 
  step: function( now, fx ) {
    $(this).css('transform', 'rotate(' + totalDegree + 'deg)' );
  },
  complete: function() { 
    setTimeout( function() { 
      showForm( 1 ) 
    }, 5000); 
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer... but it didn't seem to solve the problem. Here is a link to my git hub with all the code. https://github.com/omaracrystal/gschool-trivia

Comment: @xgrioux - Is your repository up to date. When i download and run the example i'm getting a repeated error about aoY not being defined.

Comment: @xgrioux updated my answer to a new suggestion. Let me know if it gets you on the right track.